# Capture everything with double quotes (optional) Regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex right now:

```
file:\s?['"](.*?)['"]
```

For this string:

```
file: "word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf"
```

And the output is:

```
file: word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf
```

But I would also like to capture a group that hasn't double quotes (optional). For example, this:

```
file: word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf
```

No double quotes, but can also have them (optional).

I tried making this regex, but it hasn't the result desired:

```
file:\s?['"]?(.*)['"]?
```

And the output is:

```
word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf
```

With a final double quotes included, and its not what I expected (not to capture the double quotes).

Now with the last Regex I made, I have a problem when adding double quotes again. The output is:

```
file: word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf"
```

Tested with:

http://regexr.com/

RegExp: `file:\s?['"]?(.*)['"]?`

String1: `file: "word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf"`

String2: `file: word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf`

Fails on: `file: word.124-ew/ef/?s=sf"` (captures the final double quote and I don't want to capture the double quotes)

Any solutions? I will be glad if you guys can land me a hand!
Thanks

Comment: Try [`file:\s?['"]?([^'"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qI7lS9/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
file:\s*['"]?([^'"]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC9nG9/1) (note that `\n` is added for the demo purposes only)

I used `\s*` to match 0 or more whitespace (if there is more than 1, it will match them all), added the `?` quantifier  to make `['"]` optional, and turned the lazy dot matching subpattern into a negated character class `([^'"]+)` matching 1 or more characters other than `'` and `"`.

Comment: The actual problem in your regex was relying on dot matching. Lazy dot matching requires a trailing boundary, or `.*?` will never match anything. A greedy dot matching matches too much. So, any restriction is good to go, and in this case, a negated character class is best.